# IMAP Proxy that can connect to multiple IMAP servers

Tags: nginx, proxy, imap, webmail

What I am trying to achieve is to have a central Webmail client that I can use in a ISP envioroment but has the capability to connect to multiple mail servers.

I have now been looking at Perdition, NGINX and Dovecot.
But most of the articles have not been updated for a very long time.

The one that I am realy looking at is NGINX imap proxy as it can almost do everything i require.
http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithEmbeddedPerlScript

But firstly the issue I have is you can no longer compile NGINX from source with those flags.
And secondly the GitRepo for this project https://github.com/falcacibar/nginx_auth_imap_perl

Does not give detailed information about the updated project.

So all I am trying to achieve is to have one webmail server that can connect to any one of my mailservers where my location is residing in a database. But the location is a hostname and not a IP.

Comment: hi there, looks very similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74480207/3880225 maybe it could help on this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Nginx to do auth_http with any http URL you set up.
You don't need an embedded perl script specifically.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_auth_http_module.html to get an idea of the header based protocol Nginx uses.

You can implement the protocol described above in any language - CGI script with apache if you like.
You do the auth and database query and return the appropriate backend servers in this script.

(Personally, I use a python + WSGI server setup.)

Say you set up your script on apache at `http://localhost:9000/cgi-bin/nginx_auth.py`

In your Nginx config, you use:

`auth_http http://localhost:9000/cgi-bin/nginx_auth.py`